# OpenCV3 Assertion failed on accumulateWeighted

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I try to make average background but something wrong because it way to crash app

```
cv::Mat firstFrame;
cv::Mat averageBackground;
int frameCounter=0;

// this function is called for every frame of the camera
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image; {

    cv::Mat diffFrame;
    cv::Mat currentFrame;
    cv::Mat colourCopy;

    cvtColor(image, currentFrame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    averageBackground = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_32FC3); 
    cv::accumulateWeighted(currentFrame, averageBackground, 0.01);


    cvtColor(image, colourCopy, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
```

I see in crash logs

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_src.sameSize(_dst) && dcn == scn) in accumulateWeighted, file /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp, line 1108

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp:1108: error: (-215) _src.sameSize(_dst) && dcn == scn in function accumulateWeighted
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cv::accumulateWeighted` the input and the output image must have the same number of channels. In your case `currentFrame` has only one channel because of the `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` you did before, and `averageBackground` has three channels.

Also be careful with `averageBackground = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_32FC3);` because with this line you are initializing the result image each time (so you are deleting the previous image values that allow you to  calculate the average). You must initialize this image only once in the beginning of your program or wherever.